# Discussion Board in Blogger

Tags: blogger

Is there a way that I can add a discussion board to a blogspot site?

Answer (score 2):

VanillaForums.com [supports embedded forums](http://vanillaforums.org/blog/embed-vanilla/). Alternatively, you could try [Tal.ki](http://tal.ki/) or another (non-embeddable) site like [Forumer](http://www.forumer.com/) or [FreeForums](http://www.freeforums.org/) and link to it from your blog.

This is assuming you don't want to host it yourself.

Comment: I will try this one out

Answer (score 0):

Probably not, in the same sense as you'd look at any other forum-board.

But, what you could do, is have your threads as posts, and let replies and such be comments to it. Basically, if all the different users (sadly, I can't remember if you can have multiple users at a Blogspot site, but I'm assuming it's possible) can also do threads (that is, posts), you basically have a discussion board.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I guessed that. I am doing exactly what has been said but I find that very difficult for people to follow and participagte

Comment: Having and running a forum naturally requires an audience big enough for it, so that's going to be needed before a huge undertaking like running a forum can be done - and simply finding a site that runs a free forum is probably a much better alternative than running in on Blogspot.